# this PDO OOP Method is Correct?

Tags: php, oop, netbeans, pdo

**dbConnect.php  dbConnect Class page**

```
class dbConnect {

    /*
     * initiate mysql database host,username,password,database name
     */

    private $host;
    private $dbName;
    private $uname;
    private $upass;
    protected $con;

    public function __construct($host, $database, $userName, $password) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->dbName = $database;
        $this->uname = $userName;
        $this->upass = $password;
        $this->connectDB();
    }

    public function connectDB() {
        /*
         * @var $dsn mean data source name for pdo connection
         */
        $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";port=3306;charset=utf8;dbname=" . $this->dbName;
        try {
            $this->con = new PDO($dsn, $this->uname, $this->upass);
            $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $this->con;            
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**sampleView.php sampleViews class page**

```
/*
 * include dbConnect class for this SampleView Class Page
 */
require_once 'class/dbConnect.php';

class sampleViews extends dbConnect {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('localhost', 'test2', 'root', '');
    }

    function chkConnection() {
        /*
         * dbConncect Class Connection variable access
         */
        $dbcon = $this->con;
        if ($dbcon) {
            echo "successfully Connect database";
        } else {
            echo "sorry Could not be connect databsae";
        }
    }

    /*
     * In CRUD method implementation
     * READ Method Sample
     */

    function getData() {
        $sql = "SELECT "
                . "users.uid, "
                . "users.uname, "
                . "users.upass "
                . "FROM "
                . "users";
        try {
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $array[] = $row;
            }
            return $array;
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /*
     * CREATE Method
     */

    function createSample() {
        /*
         * ini variable for insert
         */
        $uname = "රුවන්";
        $upass = "123";

        //Sql insert query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `test2`.`users` (`uname`, `upass`) VALUES (:uname, :upass);";

        try {

            /*
             * prepare Insert Query
             */
            $createStmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
            /*
             * bindParam method use for inset user data preventing sql injection
             */
            $createStmt->bindParam(":uname", $uname, PDO::PARAM_STR, 150);
            $createStmt->bindParam(":upass", $upass, PDO::PARAM_STR, 150);
            /*
             * execute insert query
             */
            if ($createStmt->execute()) {
                echo "successfully Inserted";
            } else {
                echo "sorry could not be inserted";
            }
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo $exc->getMessages();
        }
    }

}
```

My Problem was in the Second class which was sample Views. Parent Class `$con` variable can access but Net Beans IDE not Display any suggestions. prepare, execute, bind Param or any thing related to PDO db Connection. So i think my OOP method was Something Wrong or incorrect. Can anyone confirm if I am correct or not?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not strong typed - Method signature does not provide information about returned type. Variables do not have information about type. To help your IDE you have to use PHPDoc comments describing types.

Add a comment to $con property:

```
class dbConnect {

    private $host;
    private $dbName;
    private $uname;
    private $upass;
    /**
    * @var PDO
    */
    protected $con;
```